# presto lambda function variable inside string

Tags: dictionary, lambda, presto

I am writing a presto query

```
transform_values(
     string_int_map,
     (k, v) -> IF(
          some_string LIKE '%v%',
          1,
          0
     )
)
```

the 'v' inside like expression is the variable from (k, v). How can I make it happen?

Comment: The `LIKE` pattern can be constructed from an expression.  For example `some_string LIKE '%' || v || '%'`

Comment: If all you need is checking if some `v` is a substring of `some_string`, `strpos` function (https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/string.html#strpos) might be more handy